# Why does LNK2019 error still exists after I did static library in the same way as it was described in msdn?

Tags: c++, static, external, lnk2019

So I made simple static library LogCon with such code in LogCon.cpp:

```
#include "LogCon.h"
namespace LogCon
{
        static bool NOT(bool a)
        {
        return !a;
        }
}
```

and LogCon.h:

```
namespace LogCon 
{
class MyLogCon
{
public:
        static bool NOT(bool a);
};
}
```

It was compiled fine, so I decided to make console app for this MyLogCon.cpp:

```
#include "LogCon.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    bool a=true;
    cout << LogCon::MyLogCon::NOT(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Previously added and linked this library to the project, set main console app as StartUp project. Tried to compile everything but got this:

> 2>MyLogCon.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:
> static bool __cdecl LogCon::MyLogCon::NOT(bool)"
> (?NOT@MyLogCon@LogCon@@SA_N_N@Z) referenced in function _main
>
> 2>C:\DM\LogCon\Debug\MyLogCon.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved
> externals

I found a couple questions where was almost the same problem at stackoverflow but no one answer has helped me, so I just don't know what actually happened, please show me problem in the code why I got this error..

Comment: `static bool NOT(bool a)` in "LogCon.cpp" is **not** related to `LogCon::MyLogCon::NOT (bool a)`. Did you mean to write `bool MyLogCon::NOT (bool a)` in "LogCon.cpp"?

Comment: You forgot class name in function definition. Now you have `NOT` function in class `MyLogCon` **and** free function `NOT` in namespace `LogCon`.